# How to Write Complex Active Record Query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I need a Active Record Query to fetch an array. CRUDS for the models are working correctly but i need to fetch array in view file. I have following SQL syntax.

```
select FirstName from Person.Person
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesPerson
ON Person.BusinessEntityID = SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory
ON SalesPerson.TerritoryID = SalesTerritory.TerritoryID
where SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID is null and SalesPerson.TerritoryID is null
```

What will be the Active Record Query syntax in rails? Any Idea?

Comment: see here for a good ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281784/rails-activerecord-query-using-inner-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for case and tables names your query should look something like this

```
Person.left_joins(:sales_person, :sales_territory).
    where(sales_persons: {business_entity_id: nil, territory_id: nil}).
    pluck(:first_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will generate a wrong query as below

```
select * from persons 
left outer join sales_persons on sales_persons.person_id = persons.id 
left outer join sales_territories on sales_territories.person_id = persons.id
```

SalesTerritory table is joined with Person but according to your SQL it should join with SalesPerson

As it is a nested join so following will generate correct SQL

```
Person.select(:first_name).left_joins(sales_person: :sales_territory).
where(sales_persons: {business_entity_id: nil, territory_id: nil}).
pluck(:first_name)
```

Comment: You are definitely correct about the wrong query generation although `select` and `pluck` are not both required just `pluck` will do if the intention is an `Array` of `first_name`s and just `select` will do if the intention is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Person` that only has a `first_name` attribute. As it stands you will end up with the result of `pluck` with or without the `select`